# Learn Python the Hard Way, exercise 20, confused about functions

Tags: python

While going through the exercises, I came across something that, even after research, I simply cannot grasp.

Here's the specific bit of code:

```
def print_all(f):
    print f.read()
```

For the whole script: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex20.html

What's really, really confusing me is the (f) part.
Where does that f come from? What's its purpose?

Oh well, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with functions in math?

Comment: This is covered in exercise 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` is an argument to the function, it is expected to be a file like object and is constructed with an open call in the example provided.

```
script, input_file = argv
#...
current_file = open(input_file) 
#...
#here, the body of current_file is executed, 
#with f replaced by the value of current_file
print_all(current_file)
```

where `argv` (provided by the `sys` module) is the list of strings provided on the commandline e.g. `["ex20.py", "test.txt"]`

Comment: Of course! Silly me. Sometimes I surprise myself how slow I can be.

Answer (score 3):

f is a file or some other object supporting a read method that's passed to print_all. The read method reads all of the contents. The print statement prints it.

Answer (score 2):

`f` is a parameter. It's passed in to the function. For example:

```
def double(n):
    return n * 2
```

Given this function definition, calling:

```
x = double(2)
print(x)
```

Will produce:

```
4
```

You could also simply do `print(double(2))`.

This parameter passing is a fundamental part of functions, objects, and object methods; understanding this is necessary to understanding *any* Python code.

Answer (score 1):

The example they provide

```
script, input_file = argv    

$ python ex20.py test.txt
```

means that `f` is file.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is an argument and is defined when you pass something to that function:

```
script, input_file = argv
current_file = open(input_file)

print_all(current_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a name used by `print_all()` for the first argument passed to it.

```
print_all(some_file)
print_all('Hello, World!')
print_all(23)
```

The above will run `print_all()` three times, with `f` within the function containing `some_file`, `'Hello, World!'`, and `23` during each of the runs.

Answer (score 0):

You see I started learning Python yesterday. But let me try to clarify,

```
script, input_file = argv
```

puts arguments passed (the script name, and input file name) into corresponding variables.

```
current_file = open(input_file)
```

This creates file handler object for the filename you have passed

```
 print_all(current_file)
```

this called the function in question. So, you define a function like `def functionName(arg1, arg2)` as to notify how many parameters this function will take (and what's it's name going to be).

So, you have defined `def print_all(f)` says this function takes one parameter that will have local name f, which will be used for further use inside that function.